# Подключение к БД Mongo работающей в контейнере Docker

Tags: docker, mongodb, docker-compose, микросервисы

У меня есть машина на которой я запускаю два контейнера Докер:

- контейнер `Монго`
- конейнер моей аппки `tickersworker`

Все это дело я запускаю с помощью докер-компос

```
   version: "3.8"    
   services:
    mongodb:
    image: mongo
     container_name: mongodb
     environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
     volumes:
      - mongo-volume:/data/db
     ports:
      - 27017:27017
     restart: unless-stopped

    tickersworker:
    image: vtb100500/tickersworker:alfa
    container_name: tickers-worker
    volumes:
     - worker-files-store:/var/worker_files_store
    ports:
     - 2222:80
    links:
    - mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped

   volumes:
    mongo-volume:
    worker-files-store:
```

в конфиге моей апки адрес подключения к монго выглядит так `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`

Проблема в том что моя апка не может подключиться к базе.
Как заставить мою аппку подключиться к базе?

Comment: вместо `127.0.0.1` использовать имя монго сервиса `mongodb`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten не помогло

Comment: Если наружу выставляется порт 27017, то и подключаться надо по наружному IP.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать localhost:27017 вместо 127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос